# (update solution)Express web app service is throwing "SyntaxError: Unexpected token >"

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I deployed the same web app to  two Azure app services, one the fine, while another is throwing such an error. My web is based on Express, how could I fix this issue?  Looks the error is not from my source code.

```
Fri Jul 27 2018 20:05:22 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
   at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
   at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
   at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
   at require (module.js:375:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
   at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
```

Comment: The error appears to be while loading a module so it is likely that something is not installed properly on the server with the error or not configured properly.  But, there's nothing we can do other than offer wild guesses if we can't see the relevant code and configuration.

Comment: Thanks,but this error does not mention about my source code, so I have no idea to find out  relevant code.

Comment: Are you doing something with interceptor.js?  Are you using iisnode?  Does this error occur before the first line of your code runs?  If not, then figure out which module you load that causes it.  This is "debugging".  You have to problem solve and insert various `console.log()` statements to debug.  Or, run it under the debugger and step through the initialization of your app until you narrow down where the problem occurs.  We can't do it for you.

Comment: You could also compare node_modules directories on the two servers to see what is different.

Comment: `npm list` will give you a list of what it thinks is installed on each server.

Comment: I checked the  node_modules directories on the two servers, they are all the same.

Comment: Then, you need to follow the other debugging steps I listed.

Comment: What's the version of node.js runtime on your Azure Web Apps??

Comment: node version6.9.1

Comment: Please check whether there are any difference between application settings(especially `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`) of  this two web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed finally, we raised a ticket to MS, Microsoft redeployed the app service to a new set of servers.Then the web site works.

Comment: so whats the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue when I set `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to a version that was not compatible with Azure.

It fell back to a really old version of node that does not support arrow functions.

You can verify this by going to the Azure Console and doing `node -v`

Comment: thanks, this solved my issue. I downgraded my node from 16 to 12 in the app service.